# Passing code reference to external module

Tags: perl

I use an external module (say **Foo.pm**) that I don't have control over. The way to use it is like below, which works fine:

```
use Foo ();  

my %config = (
    MODE  => 'NORMAL',
    ERROR => \&my_error,    # error handling routine
);

Foo::init(%config);

sub my_error {
    my ($message) = @_;
    ...
}
```

However I'm having trouble to pass in `my_error()` to the external module when I'm writing in OO style as the first parameter to `my_error()` is now `$self`:

```
package MyPackage;
use Foo ();

sub new {
    my $self = bless {
        environment => 'TEST',
        config      => {
            MODE  => 'NORMAL',
            ERROR => \&my_error,   # WRONG ??!
        },
    }, __PACKAGE__;

    Foo::init( %{$self->{config}} );
}

sub my_error {
    my ($self, $message) = @_;
    ...
}
```

How do I solve it? Passing `&{ $self->my_error }` does not seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer depends on what Foo.pm expects as arguments to its methods. Does Foo.pm have a name; is is a CPAN package that others can review?

Comment: Ikegami's answer looks fine, but I wonder if it would still work if you used \&{ $self->my_error } (i.e. putting a backslash there).

Comment: Don't bless into `__PACKAGE__`. For inheritance to work, always deduce class name from the first argument to `new`.

Comment: I agree with Sinan, but he didn't go far enough. Calling `Foo::init(%config);` in `new` also limits the possibility of inheritance. It's not appropriate to do that there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need a sub when you don't have one, you need to make one. You can make an anonymous one.

```
sub { $self->my_error(@_) }
```

So that means

```
my $self = bless {
    environment => 'TEST',
    config      => {
        MODE  => 'NORMAL',
        ERROR => sub { $self->my_error(@_) },
    },
}, $class;
```

But there are complications. In your code, `$self` hasn't been declared yet when you try to capture it. Fix:

```
my $self = bless({}, $class);
%$self = (
    environment => 'TEST',
    config      => {
        MODE  => 'NORMAL',
        ERROR => sub { $self->my_error(@_) },
    },
);
```

But that creates a memory leak. The sub captures `$self`, which references a hash that contains a reference to the sub. Fix:

```
use Scalar::Util qw( weaken );

my $self = bless({}, $class);
{
    weaken( my $self = $self );
    %$self = (
        environment => 'TEST',
        config      => {
            MODE  => 'NORMAL',
            ERROR => sub { $self->my_error(@_) },
        },
    );
}
```

As simbabque points out, the [curry::weak](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?curry) module can simplify(?) this a little.

```
use curry::weak qw( );

my $self = bless({}, $class);
%$self = (
    environment => 'TEST',
    config      => {
        MODE  => 'NORMAL',
        ERROR => $self->curry::weak::my_error(),
    },
);
```

But I think it'll just add confusion.

Comment: Your text is adorable. I love it. I laughed out loud. It's so simple. :D

Comment: Added to my answer. (Sorry @simbabque; it's not so simple anymore.)

Comment: The first sentence still is. :) I was not referring to the full answer, just to that sentence.

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted this for the best answer with a very detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4):

A good alternative to the final part of [ikegami's excellent and detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728038/1331451) is to use [curry::weak](https://metacpan.org/pod/curry).

```
use curry::weak;

my $self = bless({}, $class);
%$self = (
    environment => 'TEST',
    config      => {
        MODE  => 'NORMAL',
        ERROR => $self->curry::weak::my_error(),
    },
);
```

mst, the author of [curry](https://metacpan.org/pod/curry), gives a reasonably understandble explanation of how that works in [this lightning talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9aCsUxfRksE).

Comment: Nice, but what a weird API!!!! But that's because a normal function wouldn't be good enough.

Comment: simbabque++ for mentioning curry::weak and a link to the lightning talk. Thanks.